# White Screen on Ionic 6 / Angular 14 app on Android 6.1 non-GMS device

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have built a new blank ionic 6 / android 14 app and deployed it to a few different devices. The app loads on all the devices but one... a Zebra ET50 running Android 6.1 and non-GMS. The app opens and sits at a white screen.

The only issue I can find is around the com.android.webview was 55. I found that the required version is 60. So I used apkmirror to download the latest version and it is now version 103. Still the same result, the app opens up to a white screen.

Is there anything else that could be missing that would prevent the app from opening on an older device such as this?

Answer (score 2):

I just faced a similar problem after upgrading from angular 12 to 14. Among the many things running `$ ng update @angular/cli` does, it updates the target of the `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json` (**in my case, from `es2015` to `es2020`**).

Reading [the documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/reference/browser-support#a-note-on-angular-13-support), I noticed that for apple devices it was suggested to downgrade the target to ES5 for iOS versions not supported by Angular anymore. This gave me the idea to **undo** the automatic change made by `ng update`. **It worked**. For the sake of being as up to date as possible, I tried with every ES version. For me, the last compatible version was **es2019**.

My tsconfig.json file:

```json
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    // "target": "es2020",
    "target": "es2019",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "paths": { "@angular/*": ["./node_modules/@angular/*"] }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

I'm still not sure why it happens to me since my device has a Webview 70+, but this fixed the issue. I hope it does the same for you.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing an issue where my Ionic app showed a blank screen when using the `cordova-plugin-ionic-chrome` plugin in my project.

I'm happy to share that I have successfully resolved the blank screen issue with the `cordova-plugin-ionic-chrome` plugin. The problem was caused by a misconfiguration in the `config.xml` file.

I double-checked the configuration preferences for the plugin and found that the `webview-url` preference was set incorrectly. After updating it with the correct default URL, the plugin worked as expected. Now, the app correctly opens the WebView or Chrome Custom Tabs based on the WebView version and displays the web content seamlessly.

Here are the steps I followed to resolve the issue:

1. Removed the `cordova-plugin-ionic-chrome` plugin using the following command:

   ```
   cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-ionic-chrome
   ```
2. Re-installed the `cordova-plugin-ionic-chrome` plugin:

   ```
   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-chrome
   ```
3. Updated the `webview-url` preference in the `config.xml` file with the correct default URL:

   ```xml
   <widget ...>
       ...
       <preference name="webview-url" value="https://example.com" />
       ...
   </widget>
   ```
4. Rebuilt the Ionic app and tested it on an Android device. The blank screen issue was no longer present, and the app worked smoothly with Chrome Custom Tabs when required.

I hope this information helps others who might encounter a similar issue with the `cordova-plugin-ionic-chrome` plugin. Please feel free to reach out if you need further assistance or have any other questions.

Thank you for your support!

---